# What is the difference between gcc/g++ and cc1/cc1plus?

Tags: gcc, g++

When I compile my projects and check the resources used by running `top`, the big CPU/memory hog is sometimes called `g++` and sometimes `cc1plus`. What is the difference between the two, and should I ever call `cc1plus` directly?

Answer (score 177, accepted):

> What is the difference between the two,

The `g++` is a compiler driver. It knows how to invoke the actual compiler (`cc1plus`), assembler and linker. It does *not* know how to parse or compile the sources.

> and should I ever call cc1plus directly?

No.